# Magic byte in Apache Kafka

Tags: hadoop, analytics, bigdata, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Does anybody know about magic byte in Kafka? What is it used for and how is it used?

Can a producer send any value in magic byte to Kafka partition?

Please share any documentation on this.

Answer (score 3):

As per [Kafka Wire Protocol Guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol#AGuideToTheKafkaProtocol-Messagesets) Magic Byte is used for backwards compatibility of message format and the current value is 0.

Looks like this is ignored now and passing any value as Magic Byte works for me.